# Stack two tables with 'tikzpicture' aligned left and right

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I modified [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/218087/102334) example to have two tables stack upon another. I do get `Dimension too large. };` and have trouble anchoring/aligning the nodes. Additionally, it sometimes compiles with things in the right place, sometimes it throws and it then looks like:

[image]

The tables do fit in the space from paper top to bottom. The slight extension to the right is ok. When it compiles it looks like:

[image]

I assume it is in the node anchor line.

**the code**

```
\begin{table}[!b]
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\node[anchor=north west,rotate=90,text width=1\textheight,align=left] (a) at ([xshift=0cm]current page text area.west) {
\begin{tabular}{@{}|lllllll@{}}
\toprule
category & hh\_mean & hh\_cons & hh\_prod & hh\_total & hh\_tax & ... \\ \midrule
now      & 35.13    & 763.99   & -61.42   & 702.58    & 397.28  & ... \\
2012     & 32.06    & 763.99   & -122.83  & 641.16    & 397.28  & ... \\
no\_eeg  & 36.93    & 763.99   & -25.49   & 738.51    & 397.28  & ... \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
%\caption{idv1meta}
};
%
\node[anchor=north west,rotate=90,text width=1\textheight,align=right] at (a.south west) {
\begin{tabular}{@{}llllllllll|@{}}
\toprule
category & ... & ps\_rev\_hh & ps\_rev\_bepx & ps\_rev\_sepx & ps\_rev & dso\_rev\_loss & dso\_rev & state\_rev\_eegd & state\_rev \\ \midrule
now      & ... & 175.72      & -159.94       & 25.49         & 15.77   & -0.27          & 190.73   & -35.93           & 361.35     \\
2012     & ... & 175.72      & -159.94       & 25.49         & 15.77   & -0.27          & 190.73   & -97.35           & 299.93     \\
no\_eeg  & ... & 175.72      & -159.94       & 25.49         & 15.77   & -0.27          & 190.73   & -0.00            & 397.28     \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular} 
%\caption{idv2meta}
\caption{Price totals and positions of grid entities on individual control.}
\label{idvmeta}
};
%
\node[anchor=north west,rotate=90,text width=1\textheight,align=left] (a) at ([xshift=5.5cm]current page text area.west) { 
\begin{tabular}{@{}|lllllll@{}}
\toprule
category              & hh\_mean & hh\_cons/\_res\_cons & hh\_prod/\_res\_prod & hh\_total & hh\_tax & ... \\ \midrule
now                   & 51.28    & 1391.94              & -366.255             & 1025.68   & 723.81  & ... \\
2012                  & 32.97    & 1391.94              & -732.51              & 659.43    & 723.81  & ... \\
no\_eeg               & 60.91    & 1391.94              & -173.812             & 1218.13   & 723.81  & ... \\
mmr                   & 27.24    & 1151.48/550.33       & -606.72/-5.57        & 544.76    & 286.17  & ... \\
mmr1:                 & 23.13    & 1042.44/508.64       & -579.78/-45.97       & 462.67    & 264.49  & ... \\
mmr\_up & 31.05    & 1151.48/628.95       & -606.72/-7.88        & 621.06    & 327.05  & ... \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
%\captionof{table}{col1meta}
};
%
\node[anchor=north west,rotate=90,text width=1\textheight,align=right] at (a.south west) {
\begin{tabular}{@{}llllllllll|@{}}
\toprule
category              & ... & ps\_rev\_hh & ps\_rev\_bepx & ps\_rev\_sepx & ps\_rev    & dso\_rev\_loss & dso\_rev & state\_rev\_eegd & state\_rev \\ \midrule
now                   & ... & 320.15      & -285.02       & 173.81        & 35.12      & -0.43          & 347.55   & -192.44          & 531.36     \\
2012                  & ... & 320.15      & -285.02       & 173.81        & 35.12      & -0.43          & 347.55   & -558.70          & 165.11     \\
no\_eeg               & ... & 320.15      & -285.02       & 173.81        & 35.12      & -0.43          & 347.55   & -0.00            & 723.81     \\
mmr                   & ... & 126.58      & -113.41       & 2.20          & 13.17      & -0.43          & 137.15   & -3.37            & 282.80     \\
mmr1:                 & ... & 116.99      & -104.17       & 21.74         & 12.82      & -0.43          & 126.73   & -24.23           & 240.26     \\
mmr\_up & ... & 144.66      & -113.41       & 2.20          & 31.25-2.32 & -0.43          & 156.80   & -3.37            & 323.69     \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
%\caption{col2meta}
\caption{Price totals and positions of grid entities on collective control.}
\label{colmeta}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
%\caption{Common caption}
%\label{cimeta}
\end{table}
```

Comment: it would be more easy to help you if you would provide complete small document  (mwe: minimal working example) with your table. help us to help you!

Comment: OT but do not use vertical lines in combination with the horizontal lines from the `booktabs` package.

Comment: Thank you, i use it to emphazise that its just two tables but four rows. How to do it proberly, the vertical lines are not 'enclosing'. i use the https://tablesgenerator.com/latex_tables# which is awesome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need Ti*k*Z?

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{rotating,booktabs}

\usepackage{lipsum}% just for the example

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{8}
\chapter{Title}

\setcounter{section}{2}

\section{Grid entities and revenue streams}

\lipsum

\begin{sidewaystable}

\small

\begin{tabular}{@{}lllllll@{}}
\toprule
category & hh\_mean & hh\_cons & hh\_prod & hh\_total & hh\_tax & ... \\ \midrule
now      & 35.13    & 763.99   & -61.42   & 702.58    & 397.28  & ... \\
2012     & 32.06    & 763.99   & -122.83  & 641.16    & 397.28  & ... \\
no\_eeg  & 36.93    & 763.99   & -25.49   & 738.51    & 397.28  & ... \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\hspace*{\fill}%
\begin{tabular}{@{}llllllllll@{}}
\toprule
category & ... & ps\_rev\_hh & ps\_rev\_bepx & ps\_rev\_sepx & ps\_rev & dso\_rev\_loss & dso\_rev & state\_rev\_eegd & state\_rev \\ \midrule
now      & ... & 175.72      & -159.94       & 25.49         & 15.77   & -0.27          & 190.73   & -35.93           & 361.35     \\
2012     & ... & 175.72      & -159.94       & 25.49         & 15.77   & -0.27          & 190.73   & -97.35           & 299.93     \\
no\_eeg  & ... & 175.72      & -159.94       & 25.49         & 15.77   & -0.27          & 190.73   & -0.00            & 397.28     \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular} 

\caption{Price totals and positions of grid entities on individual control.}
\label{idvmeta}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{@{}lllllll@{}}
\toprule
category              & hh\_mean & hh\_cons/\_res\_cons & hh\_prod/\_res\_prod & hh\_total & hh\_tax & ... \\ \midrule
now                   & 51.28    & 1391.94              & -366.255             & 1025.68   & 723.81  & ... \\
2012                  & 32.97    & 1391.94              & -732.51              & 659.43    & 723.81  & ... \\
no\_eeg               & 60.91    & 1391.94              & -173.812             & 1218.13   & 723.81  & ... \\
mmr                   & 27.24    & 1151.48/550.33       & -606.72/-5.57        & 544.76    & 286.17  & ... \\
mmr1:                 & 23.13    & 1042.44/508.64       & -579.78/-45.97       & 462.67    & 264.49  & ... \\
mmr\_up & 31.05    & 1151.48/628.95       & -606.72/-7.88        & 621.06    & 327.05  & ... \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\hspace*{\fill}%
\begin{tabular}{@{}llllllllll@{}}
\toprule
category              & ... & ps\_rev\_hh & ps\_rev\_bepx & ps\_rev\_sepx & ps\_rev    & dso\_rev\_loss & dso\_rev & state\_rev\_eegd & state\_rev \\ \midrule
now                   & ... & 320.15      & -285.02       & 173.81        & 35.12      & -0.43          & 347.55   & -192.44          & 531.36     \\
2012                  & ... & 320.15      & -285.02       & 173.81        & 35.12      & -0.43          & 347.55   & -558.70          & 165.11     \\
no\_eeg               & ... & 320.15      & -285.02       & 173.81        & 35.12      & -0.43          & 347.55   & -0.00            & 723.81     \\
mmr                   & ... & 126.58      & -113.41       & 2.20          & 13.17      & -0.43          & 137.15   & -3.37            & 282.80     \\
mmr1:                 & ... & 116.99      & -104.17       & 21.74         & 12.82      & -0.43          & 126.73   & -24.23           & 240.26     \\
mmr\_up & ... & 144.66      & -113.41       & 2.20          & 31.25-2.32 & -0.43          & 156.80   & -3.37            & 323.69     \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Price totals and positions of grid entities on collective control.}
\label{colmeta}

\end{sidewaystable}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]